# Simplify the expression $\frac{z^2-iz-1}{2iz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[there is shown expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIo33.png%5B1%5D)

If I have the statement $z=e^{iθ}$, then i don't need to rewrite $z$ as $x+iy$, do I? I can write $z^2-iz-1$ as $(z-i)^2$, but I got stuck at this point, what should I do next, which formulas should I use?

[????](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9EP2.jpg%5B2%5D)

Comment: Is $(a-b)^2 = a^2 - ab + b^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a-b)^2 \ne a^2 - ab + b^2$

$\dfrac{z^2-iz-1}{2iz} =\dfrac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}-\dfrac12 = \dfrac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}-\dfrac12 = \sin\theta - \dfrac12$

Comment: thank you, but what formulas did you use to get (e^iθ-e^-iθ)/2i into sin θ

Comment: @МаксПавлів It comes from the Euler's formula, which says: $$e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry